# Using namespace in Silex for controllers

Tags: php, composer-php, silex

I'm trying the Silex framework, and I meet a problem....
I tried to delegate routing handlers to controllers (as SF2).

But I have an 500 error telling me that the controller class cannot be found...
I tried to search for help in similar questions, but no answer worked for my case...

Here is the directory architecture :

```
Application 
|-src   
  |-App   
    |-Controller
      |-IndexController 
|-vendor   
  |-... 
|-web   
  |-index.php
|-composer.json
```

Here is "index.php" :

```
require_once __dir__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Controller;

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$app['index.controller'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new IndexController();
});
$app->get('/', 'index.controller:indexAction');
$app->run();
```

Here is "IndexController.php"

```
namespace App\Controller;

class IndexController
{
    public function __construct() {}
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return "Use of controller class : OK";
    }
}
```

And here is "composer.json"

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"App\\": "src/App/"}
    }
}
```

(Of course, I made a "composer update" to manage the updates of the composer.json file)

Comment: You either need to `use App\Controller\IndexController;` or instantiate `new Controller\IndexController` with the code you have

Comment: Thanks !
I tried so much things that I forgot to add the full path again.....

Answer (score 0):

You don't define `IndexController` in `use`, so php can not find controller class.
Change use to `use App\Controller\IndexController;` or new class to `return new Controller\IndexController();`